# How do I set the placeholder for `knex`'s` raw` method to null?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I tried invoke bulk update query on mysql using knex raw method.

```
   const ids:number[] = [1,2,3];
   const values:string[] = ['apple', null, "orange"]
   knex('testtable').raw(
      `
      UPDATE
        TEST_TABLE
      SET
        COL1 = ELT(FIELD(id, :searchIds), :searchValues),
        UPDATE_DATE = NOW()
      WHERE ID IN (:searchIds)
    `,
      { searchIds: ids, searchValues: values },
    );`enter code here`
```

However, the intended result was not obtained. 
This is because values contains a string and null, but theraw method's placeholders do not allow nulls. 
Please tell me ,How do I set null to placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

Binding array of values in knex doesn't work like that. SQL has multiple type of arrays, so those cannot be mapped to SQL unambiguous manner.

In docs: https://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings is an example how to pass arrays of values to knex.

```
const myArray = [1,2,3]
knex.raw(
  `select * from users where id in (${myArray.map(() => '?').join(',')})`, 
  [...myArray]
);
```

In this case using named bindings pretty much impossible (actually named bindings are converted to positional bindings inside knex so there wont be even performance hit because of that).